# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object(about feeditem object)

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, feeditem, null-pointer

I'm trying to add an action on `Visualforce Page` which enable end users to post messages on a case. But when I click the button, I get an error like:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="FeedItemExtension" showHeader="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/api/26.0/interaction.js"/>
    <div>
        <apex:form >
         <apex:actionFunction action="{!addFeed}" name="addFeed" rerender="out"
     oncomplete="sforce.interaction.entityFeed.refreshObject('{!case.id}',false, true, true);"/>

    <apex:outputPanel id="out" >
    <apex:inputtextarea value="{!feed.body}" style="width:98%;height:200px;"/>
         </apex:outputPanel>
      <button type="button" onclick="addFeed();" style="position:fixed; 
          bottom:0px;right:2px; 
            padding: 5px 10px; font-size:13px;" id="cpbutton" >post</button>
      </apex:form>
     </div>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class FeedItemExtension {

    private final Case caseRec;
    public FeedItem feed {get; set;}

    public FeedItemExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        caseRec = (Case)controller.getRecord();
        FeedItem feed = new FeedItem();
        feed.parentid = caseRec.id;
    }

    public PageReference addFeed() {
        insert feed;
        FeedItem feed = new FeedItem();
        feed.parentid = caseRec.id;
        feed.type='textpost';
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Umi - please use [edit] and amend your question. with all code (don't use comments). see also [ask] on how to format code

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have a `feed` class-level property and also local variables with the same name of `feed`. The local variables "hide" the class level property: you assign a value in the methods to the local variables but they are discarded when the methods exit and the class-level property never has anything assigned so remains null. (See e.g. [Variable Shadowing and Hiding in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java) for a detailed explanation.)

I suggest code something like this where it is the class-level property that is always assigned:

```
public with sharing class FeedItemExtension {

    private final Case caseRec;
    public FeedItem feed {get; set;}

    public FeedItemExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        caseRec = (Case) controller.getRecord();
        feed = newFeeItem();
    }

    public PageReference addFeed() {
        insert feed;
        feed = newFeeItem();
        return null;
    }

    private FeedItem newFeeItem() {
        return new FeedItem(ParentId = caseRec.Id, Type='textpost');
    }
}
```

(Also be sure that the URL includes the case object Id as the "id" parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using feedcomment use CaseComment this will work.

```
 public with sharing class FeedItemExtension {
 private final Case caseRec;
 public CaseComment CC{get; set;}
 public FeedItemExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
          caseRec = (Case)controller.getRecord();
          CC = new CaseComment();
          CC.parentid = caseRec.id;
 }

public pageReference addFeed() {
    insert CC;
    CC = new CaseComment();
    CC.parentid = caseRec.id;
    return null;

}
}
```

---------------------vfpage---------------------

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="FeedItemExtension" 
showHeader="false">
<apex:includeScript value="/support/api/26.0/interaction.js"/>
    <apex:form >
     <apex:actionFunction action="{!addFeed}" name="addFeed" rerender="out"/>

    <apex:outputPanel id="out" >
        <apex:inputtextarea value="{!CC.commentbody}" style="width:98%;height:200px;"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <button type="button" onclick="addFeed();" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:2px;padding: 5px 10px; font-size:13px;" id="cpbutton" >post</button>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your answer could be more useful to other users if you could include more description of why/how this is the solution, in addition to code.